# trying to send StringArrayList through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

Unable to pass values into next activity

class1

```
Intent i=new Intent(items.this,bill.class);
        i.putStringArrayListExtra("bill",sbill);     //here sbill=arraylist,
        System.out.println("exit intent.....");
        startActivity(i);
```

class2

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<String> billArr=b.getStringArrayList("bill");
```

error

> INFO/ActivityManager(64): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.items/.bill (has extras) }

It is not even moving a step from here nor getting into next activity in my emulator after the above mentioned error.

Comment: Please post more context from logcat. That's not the actual error (it's an INFO level message).

Comment: That doesnt look like an error. Are you sure its still not loading this ArrayList out of the extra.

Comment: how much items to dou have in this string's list?